# blocking space for a string in shell

Tags: shell, formatting, printf, vi

How can we block a particular space for a string in shell using `printf` command
for example result is

```
tom@x.com 10
john@x.com 11
andrew@x.com 12
thomas_sean@x.com 15
```

how can we align this result in proper manner as my command used in coding is

```
printf $user$i $time
```

result desired is

```
tom@x.com          10
john@x.com         11
andrew@x.com       12
thomas_sean@x.com  15
```

my code is as below-

```
    echo $h | cut -f$a -d" " 

`printf "\t${t[$a]}\t\t $hour:$min:$sec\n"`
```

Comment: Show more of your code.  Chances are that solution would depend upon how you're doing it.

Comment: Your code is rather chaotic. The `printf $user$i $time` part is odd — what happened to the format string and what is `$i`? The `echo $h | cut -f$a -d" "` part is inscrutable; what is `$h` and what is `$a`? The `printf "\t${t[$a]}\t\t $hour:$min:$sec\n"` fragment is baffling; again, there is no format string visible, it is not clear what's in the `t` array; what's in `$a`, or where `$hour` or `$min` or `$sec` came from, and there's no reason to execute the output of the `printf` command as the back quotes do. Please create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possible script

```
while read -r user time
do
    printf "%-20s %s\n" "$user" "$time"
done <<'EOF'
tom@x.com 10
john@x.com 11
andrew@x.com 12
thomas_sean@x.com 15
EOF
```

#### Sample output:

```
tom@x.com            10
john@x.com           11
andrew@x.com         12
thomas_sean@x.com    15
```

The `%-20s` can be adjusted a little (`%-17s` or `%-18s`) if desired, but the basic idea is to reserve an appropriate number of spaces and left justify the string, followed by a blank and then the 'time'.  The `\n` for the newline is necessary; `printf` does not add a newline unless you request it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your output to `column -t`:

```
$ column -t << END
tom@x.com 10
john@x.com 11
andrew@x.com 12
thomas_sean@x.com 15
END
```

```
tom@x.com          10
john@x.com         11
andrew@x.com       12
thomas_sean@x.com  15
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, yes this is working but i am able to do this at console not in my code. what shall i do for executing this in my code as this printf command is in for loop, i have updated my code in question, please check and suggest.

Comment: @user2663468: You'll have to show more of your code for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
printf("%-10s%-50s", $1, $2)
```

I didn't test it, but I think it will work.
If not, give a look on this [issue](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/96311-text-columns.html), someone had the same problem solved :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @devnull-   t[$a]=`echo $h | cut -f$a -d" "`
                printf "\t${t[$a]}\t\t $hour:$min:$sec\n"
                printf "\t${t[$a]}\t\t $hour:$min:$sec\n">>final.log

Comment: t[$a]=`echo $h | cut -f$a -d" "`
  printf "\t${t[$a]}\t\t $hour:$min:$sec\n"
  printf "\t${t[$a]}\t\t $hour:$min:$sec\n">>final.log

Comment: @user2663468 Instead of writing in the comments, update the question.